# How to detect the last element in a line with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this markup here:

```
<p>
    <?= $d['contact'] ?> | <?= $d['address'] ?>
</p>
<p>
    T: <?= $d['phone'] ?> | 
    <a href="mailto:<?= $d['email'] ?>"><?= $d['email'] ?></a> | 
    <a href="http://<?= $d['website'] ?>" target="_blank"><?= $d['website'] ?></a>
</p>
```

And since it's for a responsive layout, I'd like to remove the `|` seperator when it's the last element on a line. Is that possible? I'm thinking of wrapping it in `<span></span>` and call it out whenever it's the last element.

Comment: What's a "line", and where are the elements, this isn't clear at all ?

Comment: @adeneo a `line` is a line of text. That's all it is. And when the line breaks and some words are being taken to a new line if the `|` element is the last one in the broken line, it should be hidden.

Comment: any particular reason you want to use js/jquery? This can be achieved with css :before and :last-child psuedoselectors

Comment: @Jakeii ok then can you please show me a way how it's done?

Comment: This is more complicated than you think, at least if I'm getting it. When a line breaks like that there's no way to get whatever the last element is, you have to get the width of the letters and the parent and do counts and stuff to see where the line would break.

Comment: you can get jquery last selector via css, and make jquery object

Comment: Why is `|` being added to the last line anyway?  It looks like your code is not generated programmatically so there is no reason for the `|` to be there unless you explicitly put it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, if you make sure the content following the seperator a element and then check the positions of the seperator and the next element:

```php
<p>
    <?= $d['contact'] ?><span class="seperator"> | </span><span><?= $d['address'] ?></span>
</p>
<p>
    T: <?= $d['phone'] ?><span class="seperator"> | </span>
    <a href="mailto:<?= $d['email'] ?>"><?= $d['email'] ?></a><span class="seperator"> | </span>
    <a href="http://<?= $d['website'] ?>" target="_blank"><?= $d['website'] ?></a>
</p>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $(".seperator").each(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            // use visibility since it does not free the space
            t.css("visibility", (t.next().offset().top > t.offset().top) ? "hidden" : "visible");
        });
    }).resize();
});
```

**Edit**:
`t.next().offset()` must be checked for `.length`, otherwise console will show error for last element `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` (there is no `.next()` after the last element). So code should be something like:

```js
$(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(".seperator").each(function () {
                var t = $(this);
                var this_offset = t.offset().top;
                if (t.next().length) {
                  var next_offset = t.next().offset().top; 
                }
                // use visibility since it does not free the space
                t.css("visibility", (next_offset > this_offset) ? "hidden" : "visible");
            });
        }).resize();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last | char

```
function removeReverseCharLike(str,char){
    i = str.lastIndexOf(char);
    if (i != -1) {
        str = str.substr(0,i) + str.substr(i+1,i);
    }
    return str;
}

str = $('p:last').html();
removeReverseCharLike(str,char);
```

if you want to trim the last '|' char in case it is the last char in the sentence you will have to split the html string

```
strArr = $('#test').html().split('\n')
var html = '';
for(i in strArr){
  html += strArr[i].replace(/\|$/, '');
}
```

Comment: it should work.. if not you should change something in the logic